# Why do I facing this error in flutter, it was started when i was trying to generate SHA 1 key but after that it is showing constantly?

Tags: flutter, firebase, null, runtime-error

Solve this error, I was working without any error but when I was fetching the SHA 1 key than this error starts.
`E/flutter ( 5777): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:` `PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)`
`E/flutter ( 5777): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource` `(package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)`
`E/flutter ( 5777): <asynchronous suspension>`
`E/flutter ( 5777): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp` `(package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)`
`E/flutter ( 5777): <asynchronous suspension>`
`E/flutter ( 5777): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)`
`E/flutter ( 5777): <asynchronous suspension>`
`E/flutter ( 5777): #3      main (package:farmery/main.dart:17:3)`

Comment: Have you added the Firebase SDK dependencies in the Project Level `build.gradle` file and Application Level `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share the relevant pieces of code where you initialize Firebase in `main.dart` and `build.gradle`